# Null value Exception- Vb.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

```
  Private Sub Button4_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text
    Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM " & ComboBox1.Text
    Dim OleDBConn1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()
    Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, OleDBConn1)
    OleDBConn1.Open()
    OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.Text))
    DataSet1.AcceptChanges()
    OleDBConn1.Close()
End Sub
```

This code is raising null value exception when update

Comment: On which line is the exception being raised?

Comment: @BrianHooper OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.Text))
expection msg is value cannot be Null

Comment: I'd guess then, in that case, that the ComboBox1 has no text in it; you can confirm this by stepping through the code with debug and hovering the mouse pointer over the variables involved.

Comment: @BrianHooper Combobox have text , i checked

Comment: You need to debug, it'll be fairly clear what you're doing wrong. You already have the line where the error is, now you just need to see what DataSet1 contains at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim DataSet1 As New DataSet()
Dim OleDbDataAdapter1 As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(SQLString, OleDBConn1)
OleDBConn1.Open()
OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.Text))
```

On the first of those four lines you are creating a `DataSet` and on the fourth line you try to get a `DataTable` from it by name.  How exactly do the intervening two lines magically create that `DataTable` in the `DataSet`?  The answer is that they don't.  Presumably you already have a `DataSet` that contains the desired `DataTable` so use it.